# Error while installing libgraph on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: package-management

E: Package 'guile-1.8-dev' has no installation candidate

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2):

The default version of guile-x.x-dev in Ubuntu 17.10 repositories is guile-2.0-dev. guile-2.0-dev is also available in Ubuntu 18.04. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install guile-2.0-dev
```

If you need the specific version of guile-1.8-dev you can manually download the guile-1.8-dev .deb file from the official Ubuntu 16.04 repositories: [i386](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/guile-1.8-dev/download), [amd64](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/guile-1.8-dev/download) and double-click the .deb file to open it in Ubuntu Software. If you manually installed guile-1.8-dev, mark the package as held back to prevent it from being automatically upgraded or removed.

```
sudo apt-mark hold guile-1.8-dev
```